# Persian words are mixed with English

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

This my code

```
try: 
    from PIL import Image 
except ImportError: 
    import Image 
import pytesseract 
from langdetect import detect_langs 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
t =pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(r"E:\dd\readphoto\source\123.jpg"),lang="eng+fas") 
print(detect_langs(t))
print(t)
```

My photo:

[image]

**result:**

```
[fa:0.9999978843620659]
خوشبختانه, هنر پاسخ‌هایی ‎dy‏ ما می‌دهد ‎OS‏ بقیه
نمی‌دهند. این شاید حتی بکی از مشخصه‌های
اصلی ادبیات باشد: چیزی را به ما می‌گوید که جامعه
‎job oy‏ کلی آن قدر محتاط است که ‎Oy‏ سراغش
نمیرود. کتاب‌های مهم ‎sul‏ آن‌هایی باشند که باعث
شوند ‎lo‏ در کمال آرامش 9 رضایت خاطرء متحیر
شویم از اینکه چگونه ممکن است نویسنده
درباره‌ی زندگی ما بداند.
از کتاب؛ سیر عشق
اثر؛ آلن دو باتن
‎Rangigzangi.cCom‏ ۰
```

> How can I fix that? English words merged with Persian words, but I
> don't want that to happen

Comment: What happens if you convert the image to black-white yourself?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific with about what is wrong with the output

Comment: English words are mixed with my Persian words, my picture have **Persian** words, not English

Answer (score 0):

Clean the text by removing all the non-Persian characters:

```py
import re

clean_text = re.sub("[a-zA-Z]", "", text)
```